Mac Mini M2 Pro has washed out appearance when connected to Sony 4K TV
My Sony LCD TV HDMI is set to full RGB, worked fine with Nvdia cards, but when connected to my Mac Mini M2 Pro TV colors looked washed out and picture looks too bright. This appears to happen due to limited dynamic range signal sent to my full RGB TV.
Why does Apple limit HDMI to limited RGB only?? I also tried connecting via my Denon receiver, which reports signal sent by Mac mini as ycbcr444. Is there a way to force Mac Mini to send full RGB signal instead?

This article might be helpful. https://superuser.com/questions/361551/what-is-ycbcr444

There's no such thing called "limited RGB". YCbCr444 is not limited RGB it is just transformed(converted), maybe with some accuracy lost but no color is changed. YCbCr420 is additionally chroma subsampled, so you should avoid it at all costs because it causes blurry text. Be cautious when using words like "limited", which commonly mean "limited-range" (e.g. 16-235 in 8bit)!
If you see "washed out" colors it's likely due to the signal range being incorrectly set to full (0-255) in TV when the signal is actually limited(16-235). Don't know why you think picture is too bright, when this signal range mismatch happens, the whitest white is actually dimmer, the blackest black is brighter, and colors are duller.

Here's how to make your Mac mini output full RGB signal over HDMI instead of default ycbcr which some TVs don't handle well:
https://gist.github.com/GetVladimir/c89a26df1806001543bef4c8d90cc2f8
I now enjoy proper full range colors on my TV.

Please include essential parts of the answer in your answer rather than redirecting to an external website.
